# Ember.js 2.0 Struggling to make hardcoded list available in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently building an application where a User will have to correct data within a prefilled form.

This form we will have some `<select>` that can show a selected value that corresponds to the data sent by the server. And sometimes we will not have data corresponding to that select, so we will not preselect any data. The server with never send me the list of all the possible values so I have to hard code then somewhere.

For that, I thought about creating an enumerable in the `Route`, for each list, and expose those to the `Template` via the `setupController` method.

1st question: is this a good way of doing?

2nd question: the code below is what I wrote and it does not work. When I call `{{buildingDescriptions.length}}` in the template, it does not show anything whereas the console outputs the right value... Also the `{{each-in}}` loop does not work either.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed, RSVP } = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  buildingDescriptions: computed(function() {
    const descriptions = Ember.A([
      {value: 'oneFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
      {value: 'oneFamilyHouseWithSmallFlat', desc: ''},
      {value: 'twoFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
      {value: 'twoFamilyHouseWithSmallFlat', desc: ''},
      {value: 'threeFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
      {value: 'garageOrShelter', desc: ''}
    ]);

    return RSVP.hash({descriptions: descriptions}).then(
      function(results) {
        Ember.Logger.log(results.descriptions.length);
        Ember.Logger.log(results.descriptions);
        return results.descriptions;
      }
    );
  }),

  model() {

  },

  setupController(controller) {
    Ember.Logger.log(this.get('buildingDescriptions'));
    controller.set('buildingDescriptions', this.get('buildingDescriptions'));
  }
});
```

Many thanks in advance. Cheers

EDIT: This is what a simplified version of the code that works now:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  buildingDescriptions: Ember.A([
    {value: 'oneFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
    {value: 'oneFamilyHouseWithSmallFlat', desc: ''},
    {value: 'twoFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
    {value: 'twoFamilyHouseWithSmallFlat', desc: ''},
    {value: 'threeFamilyHouse', desc: ''},
    {value: 'garageOrShelter'}
  ]),

  setupController(controller) {
    controller.set('buildingDescriptions', this.get('buildingDescriptions'));
  }
});
```

Comment: it works? Instead of having the property in route and then setting it to controller, you can have it directly in the controller also.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. I did not use a controller hand because I am trying to stay away from controllers since they are getting slowly deprecated.